# Take values from active class and assume to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, shopify, liquid

I work on a product configurator that works with liquid.
*Liquid uses a combination of tags, objects, and filters to load dynamic content.*

- Every Product has two configuration options. Color and material.
- Both options appear as clickable swatches.

We would like to add the effect, that the material swatch change the background color to the color of the selected color variant.

Take place here: [http://printnil.com/products/new-standard](http://printnil.com/products/new-standard?variant=1120578371)

**swatch.liquid:**

```
{% if swatch == blank %}
{% else %}

{% assign found_option = false %}
{% assign is_color = false %}
{% assign option_index = 0 %}

{% for option in product.options %}
  {% if option == swatch %}
    {% assign found_option = true %}
    {% assign option_index = forloop.index0 %}
    <style>
      #product-select-option-{{ option_index }} { display: none; }
      #product-select-option-{{ option_index }} + .custom-style-select-box { display: none !important; }
    </style>
    <script>$(window).load(function() { $('.selector-wrapper:eq({{ option_index }})').hide(); });</script>
    {% assign downcased_option = swatch | downcase %}
    {% if downcased_option contains 'color' or downcased_option contains 'colour' %}
      {% assign is_color = true %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% unless found_option %}
{% else %}
<div class="swatch clearfix swatch-{{swatch}}" data-option-index="{{ option_index }}">
  {% assign values = '' %}
  {% for variant in product.variants %}
    {% assign value = variant.options[option_index] %}
    {% unless values contains value %}
      {% assign values = values | join: ',' %}
      {% assign values = values | append: ',' | append: value %} 
      {% assign values = values | split: ',' %}

      <div data-value="{{ value | escape }}" class="swatch-element {% if is_color %}color {% endif %}{{ value | handle }}">
        {% if is_color %}
        <div class="tooltip">{{ value }}</div>
        {% endif %}
        <input id="swatch-{{ option_index }}-{{ value | handle }}" type="radio" name="option-{{ option_index }}" value="{{ value | escape }}"{% if forloop.first %} checked{% endif %}/>
        {% if is_color %}
        <label for="swatch-{{ option_index }}-{{ value | handle }}" style="background-color: {{ value | split: ' ' | last | handle }};">
        </label>
        {% else %}
        <label for="swatch-{{ option_index }}-{{ value | handle }}">
          {{ value }}
        </label>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    {% endunless %}

  {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endunless %}

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script> 
  var mat = jQuery(".swatch.clearfix.swatch-Material");
  var colors = jQuery(".swatch-element.color");

  var colChanger = function() {
    mat.css("background-color", jQuery(this).css("background-color"));  
  };

  colors.each(function(e) { jQuery(this).click(colChanger); });
  mat.css("background-color", "#222");
</script>
```